# Carbon produzindo resultados inconsistentes

Tags: php, datetime

***Correto***

```
$datSuspensao   = Carbon::parse($objAlt->dat_inclusao)->addDays(8)->startOfDay();
$datNow         = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();
$diasRestantes  = $datNow->diffInDays($datSuspensao, false);
dd('($datNow ' . $datNow . ') - (' . '$datSuspensao ' .$datSuspensao . ') = ' . $diasRestantes);

//"($datNow 2018-10-23 00:00:00) - ($datSuspensao 2018-10-20 00:00:00) = -3"
```

***Correto***

```
$datSuspensao   = Carbon::parse($objAlt->dat_inclusao)->addDays(15)->startOfDay();
$datNow         = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();
$diasRestantes  = $datNow->diffInDays($datSuspensao, false);
dd('($datNow ' . $datNow . ') - (' . '$datSuspensao ' .$datSuspensao . ') = ' . $diasRestantes);

//"($datNow 2018-10-23 00:00:00) - ($datSuspensao 2018-10-27 00:00:00) = 4"
```

***Resultado Inconsistente***

Por algum motivo está adicionando 1 hora no `$datSuspensao` quando o número de dias adicionais for igual a `9`. Por este motivo, o cálculo fica errado.

```
$datSuspensao   = Carbon::parse($objAlt->dat_inclusao)->addDays(9)->startOfDay();
$datNow         = Carbon::now()->startOfDay();
$diasRestantes  = $datNow->diffInDays($datSuspensao, false);
dd('($datNow ' . $datNow . ') - (' . '$datSuspensao ' .$datSuspensao . ') = ' . $diasRestantes);

//Imprime: "($datNow 2018-10-23 00:00:00) - ($datSuspensao 2018-10-21 01:00:00) = -1"
```

**Como vem do banco (dat_inclusao)**
    Eu devo adicionar n dias na `dat_inclusao` como vc pode ver lá emcima.

```
$objAlt->dat_inclusao = date: 2018-10-12 18:40:11.0 America/Sao_Paulo (-03:00)
```

Comment: Não será porque seu relógio está errado?

Comment: Removi a tag [tag:laravel], porque `Carbon` não tem relação com o Framework, é apenas uma biblioteca usada por ele.

Comment: O formato de data que está vindo do banco é `date: 2018-10-12 18:40:11.0 America/Sao_Paulo (-03:00)`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters pode ser algo relacionado ao horário de verão? dia 21 Diversos aparelhos mudaram sozinho de horário.
@ErlonCharles eu dei um ``Carbon::parse`` nesta data antes

Comment: @carlos com certeza, pode. Meu servidor aqui estava adicionando os registros com uma hora a mais. O Linux atualizou sozinho. Percebi isso ontem e modifiquei a data do servidor, pra não ter mais erros.